# How do I make the Google Search Plotting Graph Larger?

Tags: google-search, graph

Often times when I'm using the Google Search Plotting feature I need to zoom out to see what a whole functions looks like, but then I also miss out on seeing the precise details. Is there a way to make the actual plotting window use up more of my screen space?

Here is an example of a graph I would like to have bigger:

[image: small graph]

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.